# Why are sometimes iOS sample apps written in C#?

Tags: c#, ios, xcode, visual-studio-2010

First, I am completely beginner when it comes to iOS development. I was asking myself, why some sample apps for iOS are written in C# bundled within a visual studio project?

[Here's an example of a simple loading view.](http://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/standard_controls/popovers/display_a_loading_message/)

What is the idea behind this? Is it only fake? How can I migrate this to XCode?

Comment: Like any platform iOS allows you to develop in a language you know. The developers from Xamarin build a wrapper around the iOS frameworks that allows you to develop app ins C#. Apple official only support Objective-C and Swift. The example you are finding made by developers using the [Xamarin.iOS package](http://xamarin.com/platform#ios). So if you have a great knowledge in one language you might not want to switch to an other language.

Comment: For the same reason you wrote a question on SO, you thought it was the right tool for the job

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanations! Does somebody know why the question is downvoted by -4 ? I don't understand people downvoting questions without leaving a comment...! It's a shame...

Comment: I didn't downvote myself (despite I [should](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252677)), but that's clearly the lack of research, googling for just "c# ios" makes you aware about xamarin, not talking what given code example linking on their website.

Comment: I downvoted  because your question doesn't show research effort, and its unclear what you are asking. your title asks why are apps written in c# but then your description mentions another 3 questions and a link which im not sure what the link is trying to show

Comment: Okay thanks again, I will keep that in mind for future questions :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iOS apps *can* be written in C# by using some Xamarin stuff. This seems to be a new feature of VS 2015. Some people just do this because they like C# more. They make sample iOS apps in C# because they want to demonstrate whatever stuff in the iOS OS. Some C# iOS developers just don't want or don't understand the sample in swift or objective C. So that's why people write iOs samples in C#.

For your second question, I don't think you can migrate this to XCode though.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!